# How do you get information from a form and put it in a table with HTML, CSS, and Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am new to HTML/CSS/JS and I wanted to know how to get information from a form and store it in a table.

For example, the user will type their name in the form and press a create button. This will make a table that has the user's name in it. However, I also want the data to stay in the table even after the tab is refreshed. I believe this requires a server. Please point me in the right direction. Below is my HTML followed by my JS.

Clarifications:
When the tab is refreshed, other people who visit the website should be able to see the data in the table that the user entered.
Every time the user presses enter on the table, it should add a new row without deleting the previous one.

I believe that I have to use a server, so can anyone tell me how to use it in conjunction with what I want to do as stated above? Thanks!

```
HTML

<form>
        <label for="name">Name:</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name"<br>
</form>


JS

function refresh() {
    var table = document.getElementById("infotable");
    let row = table.insertRow(1);
    let cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    cell1.innerHTML = document.getElementById("name").value;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, actually you don't need a server. You can save the data in `localStorage`. Check out this commented example:

```js
const result = document.getElementById("result");
const saved = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("save")); // get saved items
if (saved) {
  const t =
    `<table>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Hobby</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>${saved.name}</td>
      <td>${saved.age}</td>
      <td>${saved.hobby}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>`;
  result.innerHTML = t; // show the result
}

const form = document.getElementById("my-form"); // get the form element
form.addEventListener("submit", e => {
  // detect once the submit button is clicked
  e.preventDefault(); // Don't allow the form to redirect to another page
  const {
    elements
  } = form; // Get input elements so we can retrieve their values
  const output = {
    name: elements.name.value, // get name
    age: +elements.age.value, // get age; the "+" in front converts it to a number
    hobby: elements.hobby.value // get hobby
  };
  localStorage.setItem("save", JSON.stringify(output)); // save output to localStorage
  // Create a template
  const template =
    `<table>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Hobby</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>${output.name}</td>
      <td>${output.age}</td>
      <td>${output.hobby}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>`;
  result.innerHTML = template; // show the result
});
```

```html
<form id="my-form">
  <!-- some dummy inputs -->
  <label for="name">Name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Enter your name...">
  <br>
  <label for="age">Age:</label>
  <input type="number" id="age" name="age" placeholder="Enter your age...">
  <br>
  <label for="hobby">Hobby:</label>
  <input type="text" id="hobby" name="hobby" placeholder="Enter your hobby...">
  <br>
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Note: localStorage won't work in the above example because the embed doesn't allow it.

Comment: To clarify, the top chunk of code goes in javascript, right? If so, I tried using it but it doesn't save the user's code when I used what you wrote. When I tried to implement it in my code, it didn't correctly do its function. Disregarding my project, could you please try to find why your code isn't working for me?

Comment: Where did you run it?

Comment: I'm using VSCode and I ran it on Chrome.

Comment: What is the error message you're getting?

Comment: There's no error message, but when I reload it, it doesn't save. It just says "undefined" in the table row instead of the information I entered before reloading. However, it's entirely possible that I'm misunderstanding the purpose of the code.

Comment: @user15899303 Sorry, my bad. I forgot to `JSON.parse` it. I updated my answer.

Comment: Now it's not displaying the table unfortunately.

Comment: Did you try entering some data?

Comment: Oops, looks like my code is full of errors. I forgot to stringify as well. How about try the code now?

Comment: Nothing changed since the previous code. The table is still not appearing.

Comment: First run `localStorage.clear()`, enter some data into the form, and try seeing what happens.

Comment: Great, it worked! Thanks!

Comment: Great; sorry for the complications. I would also appreciate if you select it as the answer.

Comment: I had a question, I want to display the table on another HTML page. I tried moving the div tag below the form, but it didn't work. Do you have any solutions for me to try?

Comment: Would you like to move this discussion to chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239637/discussion-between-code-and-user15899303).

Answer (score 0):

If you want long term storage, yes, you'll want to use some kind of back end solution with a database. However, there are other options, like cookies and localStorage.

This won't work in a snippet here due to security constraints, but it will keep the users input in localStorage and show them each time they come to the page

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

```
<form onsubmit='do_fn()'>
        <label for="name">Name:</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name"<br>
        <button type='submit'>submit</button>
</form>

<div class='showname' hidden>Your name is <span></span></div>

<script>
  function do_fn() {
    localStorage.setItem('name', document.querySelector('#name').value);
  }

  // here is where you can detect it when they come back.
  window.addEventListener('DOMContenetLoaded', function() {
    let n = localStorage.getItem('name');
    let d = document.querySelector('.showname')
    if (n && n!='')  {
      d.removeAttribute('hidden');
      d.querySelector('span').innerText = n;
    }
  })
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, but I forgot to clarify that I want other people to be able to see it too. When multiple people visit the website, they should be able to see that user's data in the table. Is this possible?

Comment: Then you'll need a server.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to all of this, but how would I do that? Is there any way I can create a server?

Comment: You could use something like firebase - which is a hosted database solution with a generous free tier.